# Vector-Matrix multiplication with Eigen

Tags: matrix, vector, eigen

I want to use the library `Eigen` to do linear algebra calculations. In particular, I want to multiply a random vector by a random matrix. Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

int main(){

    Eigen::initParallel();
    Matrix<unsigned int,Dynamic,Dynamic> A; A = Matrix<unsigned int,500,15500>::Random();
    Matrix<unsigned int,Dynamic, Dynamic> s; s= Matrix<unsigned int,1,500>::Random();
    Matrix<unsigned int,Dynamic,Dynamic> b;

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    b=s*A;

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto timeMult = std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << "Result size: " << b.rows() << "x" << b.cols() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time for multiplication: " << timeMult << " microseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then, to compile it I do

```
g++ -I. -Wall -std=c++0x -fopenmp main.cpp
```

I believe everything works fine (I did not check the actual result) but it seems really slow. To give an idea, I wrote a `C++` code that does exactly the same thing and explicitly uses `thread`s, which runs about 54 times faster that the code I pasted above! In particular, on my machine it is 286904 microseconds against 5300 microseconds with my `C++` code.

Why is it so slow and how to make it faster?

I am not posting the code I wrote because it is a piece of a much larger software and making a MWE out of it would require a lot of work. Instead, I am going to describe what it does: I defined classes for vectors and matrices which wrap `std::vector`s, then to do the multiplication I define a certain number of `thread`s, split the matrix in chunks and have each `thread` calculate the linear combination of the rows according to the coefficients in the vector. Each `thread` writes its partial result in another row vector, and finally all the vectors are summed together to obtain the final result. Very simple. By the way, I am using 4 `thread`s, even though this value may be optimized.

Comment: Add `-O2` or `-O3` to the compilation command.

Comment: @AviGinsburg Thanks! I am quite embarrassed I had forgotten about this... Anyway with `-O2`, `-O3` or even `-Ofast` the time does not go below 21500 microseconds, which is still 4 times slower than my code!

Comment: Care to post the code you're comparing it to?

Comment: You can also add `-march=native` to improve performance (sse/avx), but then the resulting executable will require those extensions present on your CPU. Also, what version of gcc and on what platform?

Comment: @AviGinsburg for the code, please see the edit in the original post. As for the compiler, I am using `g++ 4.6.3` on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: So your question is why isn't the code parallelized using omp (hence the ~x4 factor assuming you're testing it on a quad core CPU)?

Comment: @AviGinsburg Yes, that's a possible question... Actually, I was wondering why it is so much slower even when using a library that should handle all the calculations and parallelization issues transparently for the programmer. But any answer is appreciated! :)

Comment: From the [docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html): Currently, the following algorithms can make use of multi-threading: general matrix - matrix products PartialPivLU

Comment: @AviGinsburg OK, so my case should be covered, right? It's exactly a matrix-matrix multiplication (since vectors are treated like matrices). Also, if I do `std::cout << Eigen::nbThreads() << std::endl;` it prints `4`, so it seems it's using 4 threads...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additionally to adding `-O2` or `-O3` to your compile flags (as pointed out in the comments), you should change the type of `s` and `b` to `Matrix<unsigned int,1,Dynamic>`. If Eigen knows at compile time that one of the factors of a product is a vector, it can use a much faster product implementation.
On my machine that changed the execution time from 25392 µs to 4751 µs.

However, you will not benefit from multithreading for matrix-vector products at the moment (Eigen 3.3rc1).

Comment: Great idea! I confirm that the execution time is now around 5300 microseconds, exactly as my C++ code.

Comment: With Eigen 3.3, don't forget `-march=native` to get AVX speedup.